# HTML e-mail sent from outlook 2007 exchange server appears as plain text IPHONE

Tags: html, iphone, email, plaintext

So, I have looked all over for a solution to this and found 2 dead unanswered threads. 
At our office we have a computer (PC-Windows XP) in "production" that sends an Email in HTML format. This e-mail contains several formatted excel Cells copied into the email body and usually a pdf image as an attachment.

When this e-mail is sent via Outlook 2007 to the Boss' Iphone (4S-Unsure of ios) this e-mail comes in as plain text format. 
When an IDENTICAL e-mail is viewed from my Iphone 4 (Jailbroken/ios 4.2.6) it shows up flawlessly.

Aside from the hardware differences between the phones, we are working from the same Exchange Server with similar settings.

Anyone have a solution or some advice on going about sovling this?

Comment: Anyone have any other good ideas? It's got me skunked, but still needs to be fixed!

Comment: Could this have to do with the fact that his phone is in the French Language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this may be due to the iPhone not being able to display the email correctly due to the encoding of the email. If your boss forwards the email to himself from his iPhone, does the email then display correctly? If so, then the email that was sent via Outlook 2007 my be encoded in UTF-8.

Comment: Is there a method to prevent outlook from coding in in UTF-8?

Comment: Turns out the problem was that it wasn't coded in UTF-8 trying to use a US only code on a french Iphone

Answer (score 0):

Here :

Settings | Mail, Contacts, Calendars, | Mail | Load Remote Images | On

http://www.iphoneforums.net/forum/iphone-general-discussion-12/viewing-html-emails-iphone-4s-34869/

Comment: I'll give this a shot, although I doubt it is something as simple as that. (But its better to give the simple options a shot first right?) Thanks for the help and I'll update as new info is available!

Comment: So I did the inverse to my phone, (Turned Load Remote Images "OFF") and the e-mail and several variations still kept their HTML formatting. ~~This did not seem to have any effect on the way the E-mail is displayed~  (even after rebooting the phone!)

Comment: Yeah, for some reason the HTML emails still seem to be hit or miss as to whether they are displayed for him (despite turning on (was already) this setting) any other ideas?